# Graphql orders api: getting weight from line items in shopify when there is no product variant

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I am getting the weight of a line item in the shopify graphql with:

```
node {
    variant 
        { 
            weight
        }
}
```

This works perfectly, but only, if the product has a variant, but not every product has a variant.
Where am i able to get the weight of the line item from with graphql when there is no variant of the product?

Answer (score 0):

There is always a variant, even if you think that you don't have a variant, you do.

Each product has a default variant that holds the price and everything else.

If there is no variant there is no way to have a product. At the end you are not buying the product, but the variant (a.k.a you are passing the `variant.id` every time and never the `product.id`) That's how Shopify works.

So you are getting the value from the default variant.